# Calculating the inductance of a coil

Tags: inductance

I can only obtain the magnetic flux density of an electromagnet coil as mT(milliTesla).

What else parameter do I need to calculate the inductance(L) of the coil in unit Henry?

Comment: Number of Turns? Area? Current?

Comment: Number of turns, magnetic permeability, the area of the coil, and the length of the coil. For a more accurate calculation you may even need the wire diameter, the loop diameter, and even the relative permeability.

Comment: I just contacted the manufacturer and asked about the inductance and the reply was: "@120HZ = 360mH, @1.000HZ = 187mH" Does inductance change with frequency?

Comment: Add that info into your question. It's both relevant and interesting.

Comment: Can you share the part number, link to coil spec sheet?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold They dont share any info besides this uselss data: http://www.red-magnetics.com/download/datenblatt/redmagnetics-datenblatt-its-ms-5030.pdf I asked the manufacturer and asked about the inductance and the reply was: "at 120HZ = 360mH, at 1.000HZ = 187mH"  I dont know how they relate it to frequency.

Answer (score 1):

B = Φ / A --------------{1}

Φ = Magnetic Flux

A = Area of cross section of the coil.

B = Flux Density

Φ = (Ni) / R -----------{2}

R = Reluctance offered by the core material

N = Number of turns of coil

R = (l) / (μA) ----------{3}

μ = Permeability of the core.

l = Length of the core

A = Area of cross section of the core.

Mostly Area of cross section of core = Area of cross section of coil.

λ = NΦ = Li -----------{4}

L = λ / i

So from {2} we get,

L = NΦ / i

L = N(Ni) / R

**Hence L = (N<sup>2</sup>μA) / (l)**

So we need to know the values of  **N, l, A, μ**  to find the value of inductance offered by the coil.